# Perl how to know parent process ID and die when parent dies

Tags: perl, collectd

I have a CPU intensive script, that runs through the query logs to parse some patterns. The process is managed by a daemon called collectd (https://collectd.org/)

```
-collectdmon(24219)---collectd(24220)-+-perl(36978)
```

But whenever the collectd daemon is restarted, the perl process will gets transferred under init and keeps on running, and collectd spawns a new instance. I cannot afford to run multiple instances of this script. I couldn't find a way to kill this script when collectd daemon is restarted as well. Is there any way I can do this from within the script, by checking the parent pid, and dies when it gets killed?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getppid.html - check for parent being '1' (e.g. init). Alternatively, implement some sort of 'there can be only one' code, with a lock file, such that a new process kills the old process explicitly.

Comment: Makes perfect sense Sobrique. Thanks a lot.